# How can I extract the user name from an email address using javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

Given the following email address -- someone@example.com  -- how can I extract someone from the address using javascript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Regular Expression with match**

*with safety checks*

```
var str="someone@example.com";
var nameMatch = str.match(/^([^@]*)@/);
var name = nameMatch ? nameMatch[1] : null;
```

*written as one line*

```
var name = str.match(/^([^@]*)@/)[1];
```

**Regular Expression with replace**

*with safety checks*

```
var str="someone@example.com";
var nameReplace = str.replace(/@.*$/,"");
var name = nameReplace!==str ? nameReplace : null;
```

*written as one line*

```
var name = str.replace(/@.*$/,"");
```

**Split String**

*with safety checks*

```
var str="someone@example.com";
var nameParts = str.split("@");
var name = nameParts.length==2 ? nameParts[0] : null;
```

*written as one line*

```
var name = str.split("@")[0];
```

**Performance Tests of each example**

[JSPerf Tests](http://jsperf.com/test-regex-vs-split)

Comment: Not sure about javascript semantics, but I would use this pattern: /.+(?=@)/

Comment: In a functional manner: `str.split("@").reduce(user => user)`

Comment: @epascarello - Why aren't you (or anyone else here) using a simple `str.substring(0,str.indexOf("@"))`? Since you have about 65 times as much reputation as me, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, just don't know what..

Comment: @myfunkyside do you realize this is over 5 years old. That could work. Make an answer.

Comment: @epascarello I like to think I can still learn from a 5 year old question. Same rules still largely apply. And if someone visits this page in 2022, I'd like to think that person can still learn something from your answer to my question.

Comment: The link of JSPerf Tests are broken. :-/

Comment: Well the answer is like 7 years old

Comment: how can I extract usernames like `this.is.a.name.with.dots@gmail.com` to `thisisanamewithdots`?

Answer (score 26):

```
"someone@example.com".split('@')[0]
```

Comment: Like the simplicity of the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
var email = "someone@example.com";

var username = email.substring(0,email.indexOf('@'))
```

Answer (score 1):

username:

```
"someone@example.com".replace(/^(.+)@(.+)$/g,'$1')
```

server:

```
"someone@example.com".replace(/^(.+)@(.+)$/g,'$2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate or fetch a username from the email with the help of this npm package.

1. [Generate username from email](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-username-from-email)

2. `npm i generate-username-from-email`

3. Use this code to fetch the username from email:

```
const generateUsername = require('generate-username-from-email')
var email = "patidarparas13@gmail.com"
var username = generateUsername(email)
console.log(username)
//Output: patidarparas13
```

Answer (score 0):

string.split(separator, limit) is the method you want

`"someone@example.com".split("@")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

My 2021 update. This will correctly output a username from an email address that contains multiple @ symbols. Just splitting with '@' is not safe as multiple are allowed if quoted.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8m6qgwk7/)

```
function getUsernameFromEmail(email){
    var domainArray = email.split('@')
    var domain = domainArray[domainArray.length-1]
    var reverseEmail = email.split( '' ).reverse( ).join( '' );
    var reverseDomain = domain.split( '' ).reverse( ).join( '' );
    var backwardUsername = reverseEmail.replace(reverseDomain+'@','')
    var username = backwardUsername.split( '' ).reverse( ).join( '' );
  return username;
}

console.log(getUsernameFromEmail('test@testhello@example.com'))
```

Comment: if multiple allowed can we split from end? because the last used @ will be correct?

Answer (score 0):

The example code below will return `myemailaddress`.

```
getUsername = (email) => {
   return email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
}

const userEmail = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
getUsername(userEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

// Input: test.user@example.com. Output: Test User
// Split user email then capitalize each first character of word.

```
   public getUserName(input: string): string {
         if (!input) {
           return ''
         }
         if (!input.includes('@')) {
           return input;
         } else {
           const cleanedInput = input.split('@')[0]?.replace(/[^\w]/g, ' ').split(' ');
           const capitalizedInput = cleanedInput?.map(word => {
             return word[0]?.toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
           }).join(' ');
    
           return capitalizedInput;
         }
      }
```