# Copy Only Domain Name from email input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field for email input and URl input field. On double click i copy mail's value to url like this

```
<script>
   function cp_mail() {
     document.getElementById("mail").value = document.getElementById("Url").value;
   }
 </script>
```

Now i only want to copy domain name of email (from the "@" to the end) and insert on the begining of Url "www." .Any Ideas ?

Comment: Please share example of email ids.

Comment: please provide what you tried. Please search for similar questions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266608/how-can-i-extract-the-user-name-from-an-email-address-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this

```
var email="test@domain.com";
var domainName = 'www.' + email.split('@')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
var domainName = emailId.split("@").pop();
```

or

```
var domainName = emailId.split("@")[1];
```

This will split the emailId by `@` which will return the array of 2 items, one before `@` and one after `@`.  Second item (or last item) is what you are looking for.

Now compute the URL as

```
var url = "www." + domainName;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var emailId = "abc@domainname.com";
var domainName = emailId.split("@")[1];
var url = "www." + domainName;
alert(url);
```