# I want to extract all the characters before "@" symbol in an email address entered by customer in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to extract all the characters before "@" symbol in an email address entered by customer in html page. I do not know which function to use in java script to extract the data and assign it to a variable. i tried substring method but it is only displaying the position of the character "@". open for help and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alert(   "somedude@somewhere.com".split("@")[0]   )`

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Just search SO or google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266608/how-can-i-extract-the-user-name-from-an-email-address-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var email = "some.body@domain.com";
var name = email.substring(0,email.indexOf("@"));
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
var email = document.getElementById("YourElementId").value;
var before = email.split("@")[0];
console.log(before);
```