# How to extract array of names from array of email ids

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this input array:

```
var data = ["ramu@xerago.com","ravi@xerago.com","karthik@xerago.com"];
```

I to output an array that looks like this:

```
["ramu","ravi","karthik"];
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't produce the correct result:

```
names = data.map(s => s.split('@'));
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into problems? Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. Please add an [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: Sure Cerbrus here after i will do

Comment: Also, partially duplicate of: [How can I extract the user name from an email address using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266608/how-can-i-extract-the-user-name-from-an-email-address-using-javascript)

Comment: I have edited the question please remove from hold @Cerbrus

Comment: As you can see, I'm not the only one that close-voted. If that is what you tried, why didn't you add it in the first place? Or did you just get that from an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, here after i will add problem and i tried code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array map:

```js
var data = ["ramu@xerago.com","ravi@xerago.com","karthik@xerago.com"];
var newData = data.map(s => s.split('@')[0]);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map`, that will go thru each item. In each item, use `split()` to split the data w.r.t `@`. After `split()`, you would get an array. You need to return 0th element of that array:

```js
var data = ["ramu@xerago.com","ravi@xerago.com","karthik@xerago.com"];

var getNames = data.map(function(item){
  return item.split('@')[0];
});

console.log(getNames);
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? I see that everyone's answer has been downvoted. Why?

Comment: I dont know who is down voted, just now i up the vote

Comment: Maybe we don't need ___5___ answers on something as trivial as splitting a string. Especially considering the lack of shown effort in the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it's more like a bulb change ... ;-)

Comment: May be. But every answer doesn't have a detailed explanation on why `map` or `split` has been used. And irrespective of that, efforts put by someone on getting the right answer should not be down-voted.

Comment: @MilanChheda: The OP just dumped a problem statement on here. Questions like that _ought_ to be closed as _"too broad"_. But on a trivial issue like this, you'll see the users flock in to get an answer in.

Comment: @MilanChheda I consider your answer best, because you actually explained what the error in the questioner example was.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this . This can be done in a simpler way

```
var data = ["ramu@xerago.com","ravi@xerago.com","karthik@xerago.com"];

var  finalData = data.map(function(email){
    return email.split('@')[0]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution

```
var names = data.map(email => email.split("@")[0] )
```