# How to extract only the name from an email in lambda node js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi am using `node js` in the `lambda` function. I need to extract only the name from an email to query the `dynamo db`. I need only name because for eg: if I give **pavi@gamil.com**. I should get all the duplicate emails like

```
pavi1@gmail.com
pavi2@gmail.com
```

Please help me to do that
 Below is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


var tableName = "Testing";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event.PersonName)





docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, data);
    }else{
        callback(err, data);
   }
```

In the above code I gave directly the name. When it comes dynamically it should be able to extract the name from an email and should get assign to val

Comment: How are you sending the email to the function? Is it in event ?

Comment: Also how are you suppose to tackle something like `kumatul123@gmail.com`. It's not a good idea to get name from email.

Comment: yes  am passing it as an event....i need only the name from an email..for eg:kumatul123...pls help me

Comment: Can u pls help me ..i think i should use string function....I don't know how to do that

Comment: See the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression.

Here is a one line code to get `username` from `email`.

```
   var emailId = event.emailId; // or any other var which is having emaiID
   var username = emailId.replace(/@.*$/,"");
```

For more use case [Regular expression for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266608/how-can-i-extract-the-user-name-from-an-email-address-using-javascript)

**For your case**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event.PersonName)

var emailId = event.emailId; // or any other var which is having emaiID
var val = emailId.replace(/@.*$/,""); 

// use console.log to see if you're getting correct username

var params=  {
    TableName:'Testing',
    KeyConditionExpression : 'EmailID = :EmailID',    
    FilterExpression : 'begins_with (EmailID, :val) ',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
       ':val' :  val
   }
};
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Sir...am getting error: "errorMessage": "RequestId: a43e3f4d-51d0-492e-bd42-ca53e94d0023 Process exited before completing request"

Comment: Where should i give the regular expression code ...in my code...pls help me

Comment: use your variable for getting emailID. I have used the generic name `event.emailId`, here you should use your var.

Comment: Ya sir..am getting the correct user name...in my log.....but my need is that i should pass only the name which is extracted from the email to the dynamo db to get all the duplicate email...How can i do that

Comment: In my code in theExpressionAttributeValues : {
       ':val' :  val
   } instead of val...if some specific name is passed  like pavi.....it gives all the duplicated emails like pavi1@gmail.com,pavi2@gmail.com

Comment: How do you suppose to get name from username ? Username can be any combination. If you need name you should ask the user to provide their name. @Samiksha you need to think on your design.

Comment: I need to find the duplicate emails...that's the reason am extracting the name from email

Comment: user emailID can be anything, it doesn't even necessary to have name. If you need name ask user. EmailID does not contain name.

Comment: Thnak u sooo much sir...for helping me